# How to parse multi dimensional JSON data that does not have a key through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have valid JSON data as :

```
{
 "bitcoin": [
    "-0.47",
    "-0.46",
    "-0.42"
 ],
 "maker": [
    "8.29",
    "8.29",
    "6.89"
 ]
}
```

How can I get values from such data where there is no key?

**Edit:** with the help of @kolzar and @FZs, I simply managed it by following code:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  console.log(key + obj[key]);
}
```

Comment: so you just want the arrays in one big array?

Comment: `obj.bitcoin[index]`

Comment: There is no key because `bitcoin` and `maker` are not objects but arrays.

Comment: And what would the output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
 "bitcoin": [
    "-0.47",
    "-0.46",
    "-0.42"
 ],
 "maker": [
    "8.29",
    "8.29",
    "6.89"
 ]
}

for (var key in obj) {
  for (var i = 0; i< obj[key].length; i++) {
    console.log(obj[key][i]);
  }
}
```

i don't know what you want. Tell me.

Comment: I want to create an array (lets say) `bitcoin`, and add the values in it, so whenever I call that array, i can get it's values.

Answer (score 1):

In arrays (`[...]`), keys are numbers.
In JS, you can access properties two ways:

- `container[key_as_expression]` or
- `container.key_as_identifier`

Since JS identifiers don't allow to an identifier begin with a number, number keys can only be accessed through the first way:

```js
data={
 "bitcoin": [
    "-0.47",
    "-0.46",
    "-0.42"
 ],
 "maker": [
    "8.29",
    "8.29",
    "6.89"
 ]
}

console.log(data.bitcoin[0]) //"-0.47"
console.log(data.bitcoin[1]) //"-0.46"
```

Since the first syntax allows expressions, the key must not hard-coded:

```js
n=0
data={
 "bitcoin": [
    "-0.47",
    "-0.46",
    "-0.42"
 ],
 "maker": [
    "8.29",
    "8.29",
    "6.89"
 ]
}

console.log(data.bitcoin[n]) //"-0.47"
console.log(data.bitcoin[n+1]) //"-0.46"
```

And there are a lot of loops, which can help you:

- `for` - The most commonly used loop. 
  To execute something on all elements of an array:

  ```js
  data=[1,2,3,"hello","world"]

  for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    console.log(i,data[i])
  }
  ```
- `for of` - More simple syntax, but keys are unavailable. Example:

  ```js
  data=[1,2,3,"hello","world"]

  for(let x of data){
    console.log(x)
  }
  ```
- `array.forEach` - Execute a function on all elements of an array:

  ```js
  data=[1,2,3,"hello","world"]

  data.forEach(function(x,i){console.log(i,x)})
  ```

And many more similar options!

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in a direction. but I have 100s of such arrays with alot of items inside them and can't statically access them this way.

Comment: @HaseebHassy I edited my answer, to be more helpful. Take a look at it!

Answer (score -2):

`bitcoin` and `maker` are arrays, so items inside have no key.

```
const obj = {
 "bitcoin": [
    "-0.47",
    "-0.46",
    "-0.42"
 ],
 "maker": [
    "8.29",
    "8.29",
    "6.89"
 ]
}
```

To get the values:

```
var bitcoinItems = obj.bitcoin;
var firstBitcoin = bitcoinItems[0];
```

Comment: I can't use this approach as I have 100s of such arrays with alot of items inside them. Thank you for the response, regardless.

Comment: This aproach is invalid because you don't know the key values. :(